# Saving all the tabs to HTML

Tags: internet-explorer, tabs, save-as

I have more than tabs opened in IE (like 10-15)

Is there anyway I can save all the tabs to HTML files?

I have googled around but could not find anything

Comment: Old Firefox : https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/saveall/

Comment: Google Chrome : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ziptabs/ccnanbffbfbcgfmmkgejodommhidpjba

Comment: Nothing for IE, switch to Google Chrome or Firefox...